# Issue with Log4net PatternLayout for WCF service

Tags: wcf, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I am using Log4Net for WCF service. I want a custom parameter "REQUESTID" to be passed to log4net.

log4net patternlayout as shown below:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %-25aspnet-context{REQUESTID} %message%newline" />

</layout>
```

I tried below:

```
OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Properties.Add("REQUESTID ",10001);
```

But its not working as expected. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that **aspnet-context** does not work in this case.

So we have to use **context properties** as shown below:

```
//log4net parameter for RequestId
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["RequestId"] = requestId;
```

web.config change:

```
<conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %-25%property{RequestId} %message%newline" />
```

Hope this helps someone looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your close, but not quite there. See the section "Context Properties" in the following link on how to achieve this.

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html

Also note that you are going to want to do this before calling XmlConfigurator.Configure();

HTH,
Eric